# How to use null safe operator in scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame like below.

```
df.filter(df("status") === "1" && df("Name") =!= "CPKabra").createOrReplaceTempView("tempView")
```

**Q1. What it is doing**

Ans- It is giving me result whose name not equal to CPKabra

**Extended- but I also need those records where Name is having null value as well means it should not ignore null records.**

Can someone help me to achieve this using dataframe?
I know after creating view it is feasible but I need to filter those records from view itself.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the filter to be explicit regarding nulls:

```scala
df.filter(df("status") === "1" && (df("Name").isNull || df("Name") =!= "CPKabra")).createOrReplaceTempView("tempView")
```